# Gutenberg List Extension Block

Tags: plugins, javascript, block-editor, list, core

I'm trying to extend the default Gutenberg unordered list that renders like this;

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

To something like this when it has a custom list style attribute selected;

```
<ul>
    <li><span></span>Item 1</li>
    <li><span></span>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

To do this I started setting up an extension with some custom attributes like this;

```
// Set up the list style attributes
const addListStyleAttribute = ( props, name ) => {
    if ( ! blocksSupportingListStyle.includes( name ) ) {
        return props;
    }

    // Add custom list attributes
    // 1. The style of the list that we want to assign
    // 2. A query to return the plain items in an array
    const attributes = {
        ...props.attributes,
        listStyle: {
            type: 'string',
            default: listStyleOptions[ 1 ].value,
        },
        listItems: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'query',
            selector: 'li',
            query: {
                item: {
                    type: 'string',
                    source: 'text',
                    multiline: 'li',
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return { ...props, attributes };
};

addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType',  'fitsociety/list', addListStyleAttribute );
```

With the custom listitems nicely lined up in an array I thought I just create a custom element and render that by using the `blocks.getSaveElement`. The docs state that it can be used for that;

> A filter that applies to the result of a block’s save function. This
>   filter is used to replace or extend the element, for example using
>   wp.element.cloneElement to modify the element’s props or replace its
>   children, or returning an entirely new element.
>
> The filter’s callback receives an element, a block type and the block
>   attributes as arguments. It should return an element.

However when I set it up like this;

```
const setupCustomListStyle = ( element, blockType, blockAttributes ) => {

    if ( ! blocksSupportingListStyle.includes( blockType.name ) && ! blockType.attributes.listStyle ) {
        // console.log( "Content", blockAttributes);
        return element;

    } else {
        const customList = createElement(
            'ul',
            createElement(
                'li',
                {},
                createElement(
                    'span',
                    {}
                )
            )
        )

        return customList

    }
}
```

It doesn't work because the save does not match the post. Which is correct of course. It is different but they state in the docs that you can render a completely custom element. I tried it using `cloneElement` but I can't get the `<span>` inside the `<li>` that way.